# Как добавлять и удалить динамически виджеты?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, deletelater

Подскажите пожалуйста как удалять виджеты, у меня есть код, который добавляет надпись и кнопку.

Я хочу чтобы при нажатие на кнопку удалялась эта надпись и кнопка удалялась.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QFrame)


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent)
        self.cont = 0

        self.btn = QPushButton('добавить')

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.add)

    def add(self):
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.l1 = QLabel(f'Имя {self.cont}')
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(f'Удалить Имя {self.cont}')
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.l1)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)
        self.cont += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Test()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Test, self).__init__(parent)
        self.cont = 0
        
        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.element_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scroll_widget)
        vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.element_widget)
        vbox.addStretch()

        self.scroll.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.element_widget)

        self.btn = QPushButton('добавить')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.add)
        
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btn)

    def add(self):
        num_element = self.layout.rowCount() 
        
        frame = QFrame()
        l1 = QLabel(f'Имя {self.cont}')
        btn1 = QPushButton(f'Удалить Имя {self.cont}')
        btn1.clicked.connect(lambda ch, w=frame :self._del(w))

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(frame)
        hbox.addWidget(l1)
        hbox.addWidget(btn1)

        self.layout.addWidget(frame, num_element, 0)

        self.cont += 1

    def _del(self, w):
        w.deleteLater()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Test()
    window.resize(200, 300)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, работает отлично

Comment: @Tesla пожалуйста.